# Android edittext underline missing when background is set

Tags: java, android, android-view

I want to set a background of dynamically created edittext and to have its underline at the same time. Now it has a background, but it does not have underline. When I remove setBackground() then underline is shown.

I tried a constructor of edittext like that but it didn't help: `etTitle = new EditText(new ContextThemeWrapper(fragment.requireContext(), R.style.editText));`

I don't want transparency on this background.

```
                etTitle = new EditText(fragment.requireContext());
                etTitle.setId(Util.getIdNotUsed(fragment.requireActivity()));

                TypedArray a = fragment.requireActivity().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(isDarkMode ? R.style.notepad_dark : R.style.notepad_light, new int[] {R.attr.myColorBottomNavigationViewBg});
                int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
                Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragment.requireContext(), attributeResourceId);

                etTitle.setBackground(drawable);
```

How to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android `EditText` underline is typically a part of the default background drawable. Setting a new background drawable would naturally override it and to work that around I'd go for layered drawable, which allows to stack multiple drawables on top of each other. That way you'd have both your custom background and the default underline, and then set that as the background of your `EditText` (of course you can create your drawable from code as well):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/your_background_color"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/your_underline_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then use it in your code

```
Drawable layeredDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragment.requireContext(), R.drawable.your_layered_drawable);
etTitle.setBackground(layeredDrawable);
```

Comment: Actually I needed to modify it a bit but generally this concept works, thumb up!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
EditText etTitle = new EditText(fragment.requireContext());
etTitle.setId(Util.getIdNotUsed(fragment.requireActivity()));

Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];


TypedArray a = fragment.requireActivity().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(isDarkMode ? R.style.notepad_dark : R.style.notepad_light, new int[] {R.attr.myColorBottomNavigationViewBg});
int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
Drawable backgroundDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragment.requireContext(), attributeResourceId);
layers[0] = backgroundDrawable;


ShapeDrawable underlineDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
underlineDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.requireContext(), R.color.your_underline_color)); // Set your desired underline color here
layers[1] = underlineDrawable;

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

etTitle.setBackground(layerDrawable);
```

Comment: Thank you for help but with your code etTitle background is like this underline color, looks like both have the same color